# how to export charts along with respective search query from splunk dashboard to pdf?

Tags: splunk

I have created a dashboard which has few input pickers and different panels. When I export to PDF, only the charts are getting exported. I need the URL getting generated on clicking the "Open Search" button available at the right bottom of interactive chart needs to get exported to PDF.

If possible the queries needs to be invisible in splunk dashboard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the value of the tokens in a `html` panel, which can be used to then show the query that is being run. Take a look at the following example.

```
<form>
  <label>SO Test</label>
  <fieldset submitButton="true">
    <input type="text" token="idx">
      <label>Index</label>
      <default>*</default>
    </input>
  </fieldset>
  <row>
    <html>
      <pre>index=$idx$ | stats count by source</pre>
    </html>
  </row>
  <row>
    <panel>
      <chart>
        <search>
          <query>index=$idx$ | stats count by source</query>
          <earliest>-24h@h</earliest>
          <latest>now</latest>
          <sampleRatio>1</sampleRatio>
        </search>
        <option name="charting.chart">pie</option>
        <option name="charting.drilldown">none</option>
        <option name="refresh.display">progressbar</option>
      </chart>
    </panel>
  </row>
</form>
```

[image: PDF screenshot]

In your case, you may have multiple panels, and each panel may have a different query. You can use multiple `html` elements, or just put the values of the token at the start.

Comment: I need to get the resolved query printed in the PDF exported. can you explain a bit how to get it?

Comment: <row>
    <html>
      <pre>index=$idx$ | stats count by source</pre>
    </html>
  </row>

Comment: I have added an extra row to the dashboard, which includes a html tag. In side the tag, I just have the query that I am running, with the tokens ($idx$), in there. Splunk will replace these with the value of the input pickers. When you create the PDF, the resolved query will be printed

Comment: Perhaps you should provide the source code of your dashboard. Remember, each dashboard panel you include will/may have a different query that is run. So be clear what you are asking.

Comment: thanks Simon Duff. <html> tag actually prints the query in the dashboard too. I am updating the question.